# How would I make a multiplication table and save it a a .txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

How would I make a multiplication table and save it as a .txt file? My current code :

```
def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter a Number:"))
    start=int(input("Enter a start:"))
    end=int(input("Enter an end:"))

    if start<end:
        for i in range(start,end+1):
            print(n,"X",i,"=",n*i)

    elif start>end:
        for i in range(start,end,-1):
            print(n,"X",i,"=",n*i)

w = tablep()            
file=open("table.txt","a")
file.write(w)
file.close()
```

How do I save this as a .txt file?

Answer (score 1):

I won't solve the whole thing for you but realize `print` takes a `file` parameter.  So to print to the screen *and* a file, you can use:

```
with open('table.txt','w') as table:
    s = 'some string'
    print(s)
    print(s,file=table)
```

If you are not familiar, `with` will auto-close the file when its block is exited.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the file inside the loop, your function doesnt return anything so w become None when and your file doesnt write anything, try this below:

```
def tablep():
    n=int(input("Enter a Number:"))
    start=int(input("Enter a start:"))
    end=int(input("Enter an end:"))

    file=open("table.txt","a")

    if start<end:
        for i in range(start,end+1):
            s = str(n) + "X" + str(i) + "=" + str(n*i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n,"X",i,"=",n*i)

    elif start>end:
        for i in range(start,end,-1):
            s = str(n) + "X" + str(i) + "=" + str(n * i)
            file.write(s)
            file.write("\n")
            print(n, "X", i, "=", n * i)

    file.close()

w = tablep()
```